# Measure string object size Java

Tags: java, memory, runtime

I created two test methods as below.

```
private static long usedMem = 0;
private static long newUsedMem = 0;

public static long getSize() {
    System.gc();
    usedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() 
            - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    String s = "test";
    String y = "testabcd";

    System.gc();
    newUsedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() 
            - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    return newUsedMem - usedMem;
}

public static long getSize2() {
    System.gc();
    usedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() 
            - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    String s = "test";
    String y = s+"abcd";

    System.gc();
    newUsedMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() 
            - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    return newUsedMem - usedMem;
}
```

I expected both methods should provide the same results, since they measure the sizes of String x and String y. However, the first method constantly returns 0, while the second method constantly returns 56 (I ran each method 10 times in a loop to make sure `System.gc()` was working).

One more note, in the first method, no matter how long the string s and y is, the results are always 0.

Could someone explain the differences to me?

Comment: I came up with the test when I tried to use the MemoryUtil class and observed some discrepancies. 

Here is my class:

`public class Person {
  String firstName = "Alice";
  String lastName = "Bob";
}`

I used `MemoryUtil` and "run time" measurement (similar to what I did above) to measure the size of the `Person` object when it is initialized but the results do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one only uses string literals, which are always present (loaded by the classloader during class initialization), so the assignments don't increase memory.

The second one only increases memory in the second assignment, for the same reason.

Comment: Following my comment on my post, the `MemoryUtil` utility returns value similar to method `getSize2()` for the object `Person`. Does that mean that it is not correct? I got the `MemoryUtil` from http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/

Comment: To make this more clear;
The compiler embedded those strings in the program, so while the program was executing assigning those strings to variables didn't increase the memory footprint

Comment: @HieuNguyen I have no idea what `MemoryUtil` does internally, or why it matters: nor do I care. The size of a string literal is not part of the size of an object.

Answer (score 0):

When performing a bunch of String concatenations, the Java compiler silently converts

`String a = b + c + d;`

into

`String a = new StringBuilder(b).append(c).append(d).toString();`

That's why the memory will increase in the second method .

Comment: Only if `b,c,d` are non-final or non-ilteral-valued.